# Point Cloud Complete 3D Area Coverage Path Finding Algorithm

Tags: planning, robotics, path

So I have a point cloud, of a 3D object, as an input which I received from a 3D scanner. I would like to generate a path which covers the entire object, meaning I would like to come up with a complete area coverage of the point cloud.

When I say path, I mean an array of points which according to a given dimension of a pixel will cover the entire object.

For example, if I had a robot which is designed to polish a piece of metal. The tool has a certain dimension which at every given moment covers a certain amount of area (pixel size). The robot needs a path to follow in order to cover the entire piece of metal. The metal piece is scanned, and the output of the scan is a point cloud. Now what I want to do is take the point cloud and generate a path for the robot to follow to ensure that the entire piece of metal is covered and polished.
So I've read that I can take the slices of the point cloud to help, but I'm not sure what to do with them?

Ideally I would like to know the normal from the object of each point of the path as well.

Thanks a lot for all the help!!

P.S. I'm new at this, so if I'm missing something in my question please comment and I will add it in.

Comment: What do you mean by "a path"? Like a Hamiltonian path?

By the way, some useful resources:
https://pointclouds.org/ 
https://www.cgal.org/

Comment: I want to generate a path that covers the entire object. For example, if I was a robot with a polishing tool and I wanted to polish the entire object, I would need to generate a path on the entire object. Not getting into the different parameters a robot might need to follow such a path, I want to know if I can come up with and X-Y-Z path.

Comment: Your example with a robot polishing the object would depend on the width of the brush used to polish the object.

Comment: What does it mean for a path to "cover" an object?   Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you are asking. Please don't put clarifications in the comments -- instead, revise your question based on the feedback you've received.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

A plausible approach is to compute a 3D convex hull and triangular mesh that describes the surface of the object.  Then, compute slices, as you recommended.  A slice is the intersection between the object surface and the plane $z=c$ for some constant $c$.  You can easily compute the slice from the triangular mesh (intersect the plane with each triangle).  This slice is a 2D path through the plane. Now, iterate over values of $c$ from the max to the min, by some small step size, and for each slice, traverse around the slice with your polishing tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out. Just wondering if it would make more sense to first try and find common faces and then when slicing the mesh, as well as saving each triangle to a slice, saving each triangle to face. And then when connecting the points, the path would be a collection of sub-paths which cover the common faces. What do you think?